# WordPress theme causes this error "Access denied for user 'nawarna'@'localhost' (using password: NO)"

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

My WordPress theme "ShowTime V3.0" is causing a database error with WordPress latest version.
**Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: NO)**
How to fix this error?

Note: The theme is old and no updates for it any more.

Thanks

Comment: put in the correct credentials?

Comment: I did, It is not Credentials issue.. The theme works fine with older WordPress versions

Comment: "access denied" looks like credential problems to me...

Comment: Wordpress themes don't normally use separate DB credentials..  Can you switch to a standard theme like twenty eleven and see if the site works? and verify wp-config.php is correct and use phpmyadmin to test those credentials.

    /** MySQL database username */
    define('DB_USER', 'DBUSER');
    /** MySQL database password */
    define('DB_PASSWORD', 'DBPASS');

Comment: I Switched to "Twenty Eleven" and it is working fine.

Comment: Then I can only suggest downloading the Showtime theme files, searching them for "localhost" to see where it's defining the DB credentials, then edit accordingly and re-upload

Comment: Something sounds really dodgy in your theme - it shouldn't be causing this error at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve the issue. It appeared that the theme is not compatible with PHP 5.6 as it used some deprecated SQL commands.
All I had to do is replace those commands with the new ones and the theme worked again.

Thanks everyone

Comment: You can define something in wp-config.php to solve this as explained here - https://www.craig-edmonds.com/solved-using-mysql_query-wordpress-php-5-5/.  I had the same issue.